# How to ignore breakpoints in DLLs in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dll

I'm using a 3rd party dll with no source code available. It runs perfectly fine, but every time I run my program, an annoying pop-up says "MyProgram.exe has triggered a breakpoint".

If I press continue, my program runs 100% correctly.
If I press break, I can see that the breakpoint is occurring in the 3rd party file alp41basic.dll

I have no clue why they put breakpoints in their dll. How can I disable them?

My question is identical to one that went unanswered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514072/is-there-a-way-to-make-visual-studio-continue-when-an-exception-occurs-on-a-line

Comment: Have you tried using "Disable all breakpoints" in VS?  It should just be a tickbox in the debug menu.  I can't remember whether that's just your own code, or all the code.

Comment: I highly doubt they put breakpoints in their dll. More likely there was an exception and you have break on exception enabled in your debugger.

Comment: If this is not the case my next explanation is your program is not really running 100% correct and you are using a dll created by a different compiler which is causing heap corruption or other problems associated by the mismatched crt.

Comment: It could also be an instance of `if (IsDebuggerPresent()) DebuggerBreak();` which could make for a nice question. Those functions may be good keywords to search for alternate approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually checked in with the company that distributed the dll, and indeed there are breakpoints in there for reasons that I won't get into. However, if I run the program outside the debugger (even simply open the binary from windows), these popup windows do not occur.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: This works, but it will be awfully hard to debug your application without a debugger attached. Instead, try Debug -> Disable All Breakpoints.

Comment: @ Cody Thanks; unfortunately I can't find that option in the Debug menu. There's a "delete all breakpoints" but it is grayed out. 
Moreover I can actually debug, I just have to click away those annoying popups!